# Boatstrap calendar disable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am unable to disable the previous date from the current data.

Check my code -

```js
$(function() {
                window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
                //$('#dp1').datepicker({minDate: 0});


                /*$('#dp1').datepicker({startDate: '-0m'}).on('changeDate', function() {
                 $('#dp1').datepicker('hide');
                 });*/

                /*var date = new Date();
                 date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
                 $('#dp1').datepicker({startDate: date});*/


                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

                $('#dp1').datepicker({
                    startDate: date
                });

            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://vanceblackburn.com/Demo/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<link href="http://vanceblackburn.com/Demo/datepicker/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vanceblackburn.com/Demo/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" />


<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Default Datepicker</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="dp1" type="text" value="" size="16" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
```

In my datepicker calendar I want to disable previous date from the currnt date.

If today is `30-June-2015` then all the previous date must disabled. Only show the date but not click-able previous date.

Same code is here [Boatstrap Datepicker](http://vanceblackburn.com/Demo/datepicker/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should initialize a temporary variable with `todays` date and set it to the `datepicker`, like this

**JS Code:**

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0); //temporary variable with todays date

$('#dp1').datepicker({
  startDate: today,
  orientation: 'top' // will display the datepicker at bottom, as its 
                     //opposite to the orientation given, refer 
                     // https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1035
});
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input id="dp1" type="text" value="" size="16" class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/py7uotyf/3**

*Note : there has been a issue already raised on Orientation (keyword opposite to the actuals) on github, https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1035*.

Comment: Yes your code is working fine. But when I put same code in my code that is not working. :(

Comment: @chinu : thats strange, can you are using correct `id` for `datepicker`

Comment: could you replicate the same on the jsfiddle which i have provided ?

Comment: Its working while I am changing the `bootstrap-datepicker.js ` to `bootstrap-datepicker.min.js` But calendar always coming on the top of the textbox :( i need it absolute position. if my textbox is bottom then calendar is showing in the top of that textbox. If textbox is top then calendar is showing below of the textbox.

Comment: @chinu : there are lot of  `orientation`  options present for `datepicker` here, you can choose the same . http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox . like this  `$('#dp2').datepicker({
     orientation: 'bottom auto'
});`

Comment: Apology there is a small correction, the orientation is opposite . `top` means `bottom` and vice versa, so use orientation as `top` . https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/py7uotyf/3/